# Kubuntu 14.04 - Wireless network dissabed by hardware switch

Tags: wireless, kubuntu

I am trying to install the newest Kubuntu 14.04 on my [Asus u32u](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/U32U/specifications/), however, i am having problems with "Wireless network disabled by hardware switch". I have tried "[rfkill](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rfkill) unblock all" without any luck, if i use my keyboard to enable/disable wifi using the <kbd>FN;</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> key for wifi, it gets enabled for a few seconds and then goes back to being disabled. `rfkill unblock all` shows:

```
phy0 wireless network:
Soft Blocked: no
Hardware blocked: yes
```

However, if i put the computer to sleep mode, and then wake it again, wifi works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the module *asus_nb_wmi*  loaded? Check:

```
lsmod | grep asus
```

If so, please try:

```
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf
```

Reboot and see if your wireless key combination is working as expected.

Comment: That did the trick :)