# Operation not possible due to RF-kill, phy0 hard blocked

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, rfkill

---

I know there are already plenty of questions like this one; the problem is that, although I tried to follow the instructions, I couldn't have my wifi to work.

I re-installed Lubuntu 14.04 on my netbook yesterday because of some other problems I was having ("waiting for network configuration" on startup and I couldn't log in (after entering the password, I was given a black screen and then back to the login screen)).

Anyway, I was able to use the netbook properly for a few hours; then I got back home, and the wifi wasn't working anymore.

I tried `# ifconfig wlan0 up` and I got `SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not possible due to RF-kill`.

```
# rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

The problem is most likely with the phy0 "hard blocked". Using `rfkill unblock all` didn't do anything. I am pretty sure I don't have any wifi buttons on the netbook (asus 1225c), apart from <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. When I try the previous combination of keys I get

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Somebody said to try to remove `/dev/rfkill`, and it still didn't work.

I restored the BIOS to the default settings, and even made sure that WLAN was Enabled.

I then tried to boot from a live distro (the lubuntu 14.04) and I still got the very same problem.

Do you have any other ideas on what could be causing this problem? I am starting to think that it is due to some hardware problem but it seems unlikely, since it was working just fine a couple of hours earlier.

Thank you!

Comment: Is this helpful? http://askubuntu.com/questions/496043/kubuntu-14-04-wireless-network-dissabed-by-hardware-switch/496052#496052

Comment: Nope, the module _asus_nb_wmi_ isn't loaded

Comment: Anything named asus?

Comment: Indeed, http://pastebin.com/tjBFDuER !

Answer (score 2):

If that is an Asus Seashell eee-pc, check that you have wireless enabled on your BIOS.

1. Press <kbd>F2</kbd> at boot
2. Select **Advanced**
3. Select **Onboard Device Configuration**
4. Set **Onboard WLAN Disabled** to ***Enabled***

For some reason, it was disabled for me, and that didn't prevent me from connecting to wireless until now.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you experimentally unload asus-wmi:

```
sudo modprobe -r asus-wmi
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

Now does your wireless work? If so, let's blacklist the module:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist asus-wmi"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work. I had to unload _eeepc_wmi_ as well, since it was using _asus_wmi_, but it didn't work anyway.

Comment: Any improvement with eeepc removed and asus still present? sudo modprobe asus-wmi && sudo modprobe -r eeepc-wmi

Comment: I tried to remove eeepc_wmi, and lsmod doesn't display asus_wmi anymore; then, when I re-insert asus_wmi, it re-inserts eeepc_wmi as well: http://pastebin.com/eUPQWk1V

Comment: You might try resetting the BIOS to defaults. Aside from that, I regret I am out of ideas.

Comment: As I mentioned in the original question I tried that, and didn't work. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Just look for your **wifi key on your keyboard** (near the function keys).

Mine was <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> (Hit <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> to turn it on).

If you can't find it you can also attach a keyboard which has the wifi key to your laptop.

[image: symbolic picture of wifi key]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an ASUS PC which had the same issue, solved by adding this to `/etc/modprob.d/blacklist.conf`:

```
blacklist wmi
blacklist asus-wmi
blacklist asus-nb-wmi
blacklist asus-nb-wmi
blacklist asus_nb_wmi
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a Dell Inspiron laptop (persisted with WLAN set to Enabled in BIOS), which I solved as follows:
In the BIOS, in Wireless section, there is another option that controls what is enabled/disabled via keyboard/software, with options {none, WLAN only, Bluetooth only, both}. Setting this option to 'none' solved the problem (obviously this prevents any kernel module from disabling the WLAN via software, so you do not have to bother resolving which module does this and blacklisting it).